# Difference between two Times in Minutes are coming as negative

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I have a method which takes two String parameters. the two strings are Time values in 24 hour format. The Times are picked using a TimePicker from UI.

The goal of the method is to get the duration between the `StartTime` and `EndTime` in Minutes.

```
public static String getTimeDuration(String StartTime24, String EndTime24)
{
    String duration = "";

    try 
    {
        SimpleDateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date startTime = parseFormat.parse(StartTime24);
        Date endTime = parseFormat.parse(EndTime24);

        long mills = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
        long minutes = mills/(1000 * 60);

        duration = "(" + minutes + " Minutes)";
    }
    catch(ParseException ex)
    {
        // exception handling here
    }

    return duration;
}
```

The method works fine if both the times are within a Single Date. For example:

```
StartTime = 22:15
EndTime = 23:51
Output = (96 Minutes)
```

But my problem is, the method returns negative if the end time is after 12'o clock at night. For example,

```
StartTime = 23:51
EndTime = 0:55
Output = (-1376 Minutes)
What I want: (64 Minutes)
```

How can get the duration correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no date used, you have to check first if your `endTime` is less than your `startTime`. If yes, then your `endTime` is on the next day and you have to add 1 day/86 400 000 milliseconds. Then you will have your desired result.

Just add this condition:

```
if(endTime.getTime() < startTime.getTime()){  

   long mills = ((endTime.getTime() + 86400000) - startTime.getTime());  1 day = 86 400 000 mill

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You're only parsing the minutes and hours.  There's no day on there.  So that puts both times on the same day (the first day of the epoch, Jan 1 1970 to be exact).  So the answer is correct.  If you want it to treat the end time as the next day if its earlier than the start time, then add 1 day to the result (1440 minutes) if the result is less than 0.